# LambdaExpression.CompileToMethod not working with System.Type?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, expression-trees

I am trying to make a programming language. The problem occurs when trying compile lambda into a module, more precisely when trying to convert from string to t(some type) using Convert.ChangeType instead of t.Parse. If I use LambdaExpression.Compile and using DynamicInvoke on the delegate it works, but if I use CompileToMethod and generate a module(abc.exe) and convert using Convert.ChangeType it throws an exception when I run the module: 
*System.TypeAccessException was unhandled
  Message=Attempt by method 'Foo.Main()' to access type 'System.RuntimeType' failed.*

---

Method used to convert:

```
        private static Expression ConvertExpression<T>(Expression exprToConvert)
    {
        Type[] types = new Type[] { typeof(object), typeof(Type) };
        MethodInfo changeTypeMethod = typeof(System.Convert).GetMethod("ChangeType", types);
        Expression convertedExprAsObject = Expression.Call(changeTypeMethod, exprToConvert, Expression.Constant(typeof(T)));      
        return Expression.Convert(convertedExprAsObject, typeof(T));
    }
```

Comment: Does `Compile()` work? also: I found locally that you might want `Expression.Convert(exprToConvert, typeof(object))` in the `.Call`, to handle value-type expressions

Comment: Are sure you want `Convert.ChangeType` and not just a simple cast?

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for you quick answer, yes Compile() works, I tried conversion from string to int and it works, but not with CompileToMethod. Hi leppie by simple cast you mean, Expression.Convert?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the exception you got (that was the hardest part :-)).  Then I was able to see if changing the following code made a difference:

```
 Expression.Constant(typeof(T))
```

to:

```
 Expression.Constant(typeof(T), typeof(Type))
```

With just that one small change it all seemed to work correctly.  Creating the Constant as being of type Type makes everything happy.